# abantecart manufacturer display

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller, cart

I am having an issue trying to show the Manufacturer of each item on the home page.

In the product_list file located inside templates/blocks I added

```
    echo $item['manufacturer']
```

under the blurb section but I can't seem to get the manufacturer to show up.

After studying and following the example of other pages which load the manufacturer's of different products I used the same variable:

```
    $manufacturer and $text_manufacturer
```

but neither brought the desired effect either.

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now. Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Template debug mode is the best way to define what tpl has been used for block.
Just enable it viw admin menu->system->settings->system and click on link once after settings page reload. You will see markers for each block on storefront side with descriptions.